# Saving Uploaded File Path in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to upload a file, and save the path to MySQL.

I want to make a custom path for each file, which will be based on a variable, however the actual file name of the file will stay the same.

I am submitting the file via POST. I believe I have to use $_FILE? The name of the form item is "file".

How would I go about doing this? Note: I DO NOT want to store the actual file on the database, just the path.

EDIT: I also want to save the actual file to a path, too.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php There is an example of moving an uploaded file to some folder.

So yes the relevant information is stored in $_FILE

Answer (score 0):

First create appvars.php like something below

```
<?php
  // Define application constants
  define('GW_UPLOADPATH', 'foldername/');
  define('GW_MAXFILESIZE', 32768);      // 32 KB
?>
```

then create the code to save the file like something like this

```
<?php
  require_once('appvars.php');

  $file = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_FILES['file']['name']));
  $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
  $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
   //do some checks to make sure the person upload the file type you like
   if ((($file_type == filetype) // check for the size also
    && ($file_size > 0) && ($file_size <= GW_MAXFILESIZE)) {
    if ($_FILES['file']['error'] == 0) {
      // Move the file to the target upload folder
      $target = GW_UPLOADPATH . $file;
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        // Write the data to the database
        mysqli_connect( database info);
        $query = "INSERT INTO table (file ) VALUES ($file)";
        mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
      }
    }
  }
  mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
```